# Android Service Button click Automaticaliy

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a button in main `Activity` which performs some function when we click it.

I want to write a `service` so that button will be clicked automatically even when the App is closed.

How can I implement this logic?

Comment: why don't you schedule via JobScheduler to do the task you needed.

Comment: Can you please add some of your code which reflects the current state of your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by sending an `Intent()` with a `Bundle()` from the service to your main Activity.

The code in the service would be like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);

Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("action", "press_button");

intent.putExtras(extras);
```

In the main Activity you have to catch the intend and extract the `Bundle()` by the following code inside `onCreate()`:

```
onCreate() {
...

Intent intent = getIntent();

Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

String action = bundle.getString("action")
// action now should be "press_button"
// now handle this information like
if (action != null) {
    if (action.equals("press_button") {
        // call the function you like
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button can't be clicked automatically inside the service when app is closed and it is not the best practice.Just create a new function and write all actions in that new function which is to be performed on button click and in service call that function.